# "string_to_term/1"?

Tags: erlang, type-conversion

Is there any function in Erlang with this behavior?:

```
a_function_id_like_to_have("{1,2,{3,4}}") % => {1,2,{3,4}}
```

(Like `read` in Haskell)

Comment: You can look at https://gist.github.com/goofansu/5159720, fetched from otp src code.

Comment: If you are reading the terms from a file, you can use file:consult; http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#consult-1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at slide 25 of [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/dennisbyrne/dsls-in-erlang-presentation).

It makes use of [`erl_eval`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_eval.html#expr-2), [`erl_parse`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_parse.html#parse_exprs-1), and [`erl_scan`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_scan.html#string-1).

```
1> {ok, Tokens, _} = erl_scan:string("{1,2,{3,4}}.").
{ok,[{'{',1},
     {integer,1,1},
     {',',1},
     {integer,1,2},
     {',',1},
     {'{',1},
     {integer,1,3},
     {',',1},
     {integer,1,4},
     {'}',1},
     {'}',1},
     {dot,1}],
    1}
2> {ok, Abstract} = erl_parse:parse_exprs(Tokens).
{ok,[{tuple,1,
            [{integer,1,1},
             {integer,1,2},
             {tuple,1,[{integer,1,3},{integer,1,4}]}]}]}
3> Bindings = erl_eval:new_bindings().
[]
4> {value, Value, _} = erl_eval:exprs(Abstract, Bindings).
{value,{1,2,{3,4}},[]}
5> erlang:display(Value).
{1,2,{3,4}}
true
```

Comment: Just make sure you check your input, as it can contain any valid Erlang *expression*, such as `erlang:halt().` In this sense, its behaviour differs a lot from that of `file:consult/1`.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [`erl_scan:string/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_scan.html#string-1) and [`erl_parse:parse_term/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_parse.html#parse_term-1).

```
string_to_term(Str) ->
    {ok, Tokens, _} = erl_scan:string(Str),
    {ok, Term} = erl_parse:parse_term(Tokens),
    Term.
```

Make sure `Str` is dot terminated.